# Flux of vector field across surface S

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

The question I am working on is:

*Let S be the part of the plane $1\!x + 3\!y + z = 3$ which lies in the first octant, oriented upwards. Find the flux of the vector field $\mathbf{F} = 3\mathbf{i} + 2\mathbf{j} + 3\mathbf{k}$ across the surface S.*

**My work so far:**

$\int F dS$

Parametrization: $T: (x, y, 3-3y-x)$

$T_x  (1, 0, -1)$

$T_y  (0,1,-3)$

$T_x \times T_y (-1,3,1)$

This is the correct orientation (going upwards).

$\int \int (3,2,3) \cdot (-1,3,1)dxdy = -3+6+3 = 6$

$\int\int6dxdy$ with $0 \leq x \leq 3-3y$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1/3$

This isn't yielding me the correct answer. I think my bounds are incorrect but I'm a bit stumped on how to find the correct ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the parametric equation of the surface be

$${\bf{r}} = {\bf{r}}(u,v)$$

Then the flux across the surface is give by

$$\eqalign{
  & \varphi  = \int\limits_S {{\bf{F}}({\bf{x}}(u,v)).d{\bf{a}}}   \cr 
  & d{\bf{a}} = \frac{{\partial {\bf{r}}}}{{\partial u}} \times \frac{{\partial {\bf{r}}}}{{\partial v}}dudv \cr} $$

Now, consider the following

$$\eqalign{
  & {\bf{r}} = x{\bf{i}} + y{\bf{j}} + \left( {3 - x - 3y} \right){\bf{k}}  \cr 
  & \frac{{\partial {\bf{r}}}}{{\partial x}} = {\bf{i}} - {\bf{k}},\,\,\,\,\,\frac{{\partial {\bf{r}}}}{{\partial y}} = {\bf{j}} - 3{\bf{k}}  \cr 
  & \frac{{\partial {\bf{r}}}}{{\partial x}} \times \frac{{\partial {\bf{r}}}}{{\partial y}} = \left( {{\bf{i}} - {\bf{k}}} \right) \times \left( {{\bf{j}} - 3{\bf{k}}} \right) = {\bf{i}} + 3{\bf{j}} + {\bf{k}}  \cr 
  & d{\bf{a}} = \frac{{\partial {\bf{r}}}}{{\partial x}} \times \frac{{\partial {\bf{r}}}}{{\partial y}}dxdy = \left( {{\bf{i}} + 3{\bf{j}} + {\bf{k}}} \right)dxdy  \cr 
  & {\bf{F}}({\bf{x}}) = 3{\bf{i}} + 2{\bf{j}} + 3{\bf{k}}  \cr 
  & {\bf{F}}({\bf{x}}).d{\bf{a}} = 3 + 6 + 3 = 12\,dxdy\cr} $$

and hence

$$\eqalign{
  & \varphi  = \int_{y = 0}^1 {\left( {\int_{x = 0}^{3 - 3y} {12dx} } \right)dy}  = \int_{y = 0}^1 {12(3 - 3y)dy}  = 36\int_{y = 0}^1 {(1 - y)dy}   \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\, = 36\left. {\left( {y - \frac{{{y^2}}}{2}} \right)} \right|_0^1 = 18 \cr} $$

---

**Your Mistakes**

1) The normal was wrong.

2) The bounds was wrong.

Comment: Why exactly does y go from 0 to 1?

Comment: @KommanderKitten: Take a look at the picture below. The domain of the integration is **the right triangle** in the $xy$ plane. How do you describe that region? :)

Comment: Aha, the projection is what I was messing up. When projected onto the $xy$ plane, $y$ does indeed go from 0 to 1. Thank you!

Comment: @mvw: Ooops! Yes! Typo! I will fix that. :)

Answer (score 2):

The normal is $n = (1,3,1)$, there was the error.
The projected area onto the $x$-$y$-plane is $A_p = 3/2$.
The flux is $\Phi=(F\cdot n)\,A_p =  ((1,3,1) \cdot (3,2,3))\, 3/2 = 18$.

[image]

([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyH8x.jpg))

Comment: I see my mistake with the normal. Could you write out your work (if you have time)? I think my bounds were still wrong, and I'd like to see where exactly (besides the careless one of the normal) I made my mistakes.

Comment: The bounds looked good. I prepare a visualization.

Comment: @mvw: Can I ask that what was the software that you drew this with? :) Voted Up for the nice art work! :)

Comment: GeoGebra 5 on iPad. I love it. 2D, 3D, scriptable via JavaScript, CAS. Deserved better docs. Should be perfect for schools. A portable Java app for PC.

Comment: @mvw: Does it have any versions for androids! It seems to be a nice app! Thanks for introducing it! :)

Comment: Yes. http://www.geogebra.org/download I use it on Windows 7, iOS 9 and Linux. On Linux there is no 3D support on my old Debian. You can transfer data via their free cloud service.